# How does hstore internally store the data?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm using the postgresql hstore extension and curious how the data is stored internally. Please point me to where I could look in the hstore source code to see the implementation details.

Answer (score 9):

`hstore` is part of the main PostgreSQL distribution, which is on http://git.postgresql.org/ and GitHub. [Here is `hstore` in git head](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=tree;f=contrib/hstore;h=d81f5646750d4d0af626d5037f7fae4432433085;hb=master).

It looks like it's stored as a varlena, which means it's TOASTable like anything else. The downside is that the whole field needs to be read from disk - at least if it's compressed - to extract a key.

This also means that like any other normal field value, **updating any part of the field requires that a new copy of the whole tuple (row) must be written to the table** and the old one marked for expiry when it's no longer visible to any active transactions (see [MVCC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html) in the Pg manual). A big `hstore` is thus undesirable for data that will change frequently, since you'll need to rewrite the whole thing (and the row that contains it) whenever any part of it changes.

- [`hstore.h`](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=contrib/hstore/hstore.h;h=23c8a6f0e288d1251ef9fb154c057fa86926adcf;hb=master)
- [`hstore_io.c`](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=contrib/hstore/hstore_io.c;h=e84cdd69051c9205683e16b90234f379998a23c0;hb=master)

The sources don't seem to contain much in the way of comments to provide an overview of how hstore values are structured and stored, and it's a bit of a macro forest to take in quickly.

Answer (score 3):

The storage itself is fairly unsurprising.

The fun part is how that's indexed to be able to answer efficiently queries like

select osm_id, name, tags from planet_osm_line where 'frequency => 16.7, railway => "rail"' <@ tags;

(this is from a real example) meaning: "find all records where the (hstore) field "contains" the mappings frequency => 16.7 and railway => rail.

CAVEAT: this is just from memory.

There are two components to that:

First is the [GiST index](http://gist.cs.berkeley.edu/), which can be viewed as a kind of "sloppy B-Tree" which sometimes doesn't tell you exactly which branch to take, but gives you some set of branches. PostgreSQL uses that for things like geometrical indexes (where you can query whether a point is in a polygon, e.g.). The index doesn't give you a perfect hit, but potentially reduces the search space considerably.

Second there is an encoding of the "hash" (for you Perlists) / "dictionary" (for you Pythonists) to take advantage of GiST: you hash each key and each key/value pair of the hash into a small int (details are fuzzy, but let's assume 0..255), take a bitfield this size and poke a hole into your bit field for each one of those hash values you get (I think Knuth had a nice example with index cards having open/closed holes on their rim and knitting needles -- yes, [here it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_card).

Then you've only to marry those two. AFAIR Oleg Bartunov and Theodor Tsigaev came up with that. My head exploded the first time I saw that.